# Calculating Probabilities from a Piece Wise CDF

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a random variable $X$ having cdf

$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} {1} & \text{$x \geq 3.5$} \\ \frac{6}{7} & \text{$0 \leq x \lt 3.5$} \\ \frac{2}{7} & \text{$-1 \leq x \lt 0$} \\{0} & \text{$x \lt -1$}\end{cases}$$

(a) What is the value of P($X$ = $0$)

(b) What is the value of P($X \leq$ $\frac{2}{7}$)

(c) What is the value of P($X$ $\gt$ $0$)

**Attempted Solution:**

I just want to make sure I'm interpreting cdf's correctly. Is it true, for example, that P($X$ $\lt$ $1$) = P($X$ $\lt$ $3.4$) in this situation, since they are both contained in the interval $0 \leq x \lt 3.5$?

(a) $\frac{6}{7}$-$\frac{2}{7}$=$\frac{4}{7}$

(b) $\frac{6}{7}$

(c) $1$-$\frac{2}{7}$=$\frac{5}{7}$

Comment: You have it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful in situations like this: there are two conventions for CDFs, one is $P(X \leq x)$ and the other is $P(X<x)$. At points where the CDF is discontinuous, these change formulae around a little bit. The most important thing that changes is that in the former convention

$$P(X=x)=F(x)-\lim_{y \to x^-} F(y)$$

whereas in the latter convention

$$P(X=x)=\lim_{y \to x^+} F(y) - F(x).$$

Since the CDF you gave us is right-continuous, you are using the former convention (which is by far the more common one in the literature).

With that said: your answers for a and b are right. You made a simple mistake in part c (related closely to this issue about conventions, actually).

Comment: Can you cite a source for the convention $P(X<x)$?  I can't find one.

Comment: @paw88789 I have heard that it was the standard in Russian literature in the Cold War and before.

Comment: The answer for c is wrong or the logic is wrong?

Comment: @JohnH Both. You do want $1-F_X(0)$, you just evaluated $F_X(0)$ wrong.

Comment: Oh right, it should be 1 - P($X$ $\leq$ 0) = $\frac{1}{7}$?

Comment: @JohnH That's right.

Comment: @Ian Thanks.  I'd never heard that before.  Interesting!